# get all elements that have attribute x

Tags: javascript, polymer, dart-polymer, web-component

Im having trouble searching for this on the polymer docs. I was wondering if anyone here can point me to or show me an example of a way to get all elements that have a particular attribute. For instance:

the component:

```
<polymer-element name="prpl-inview" attributes="">
    <template class="{{count}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="prpl-inview.css">
        <content select="*"></content>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

and the element in the dom:

```
<prpl-inview>
    <h1>Misc element not important</h1>
    <div keyframe="20">get this element</div>
</prpl-inview>
```

I want all the elements with attribute keyframe but I dont care about the other elements. If this makes any sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[keyframe]");
```

Comment: yup this was it. Not sure why this escaped me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the queryselector:

`var elementList = document.querySelectorAll('[keyframe]');`

You can also select a specific keyframe with

`var element = document.querySelector('[keyframe=20]');`

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the ordinary DOM querySelector?

```
document.querySelectorAll('[keyframe]')
```